# Can we construct a smooth local coordinate on a smooth manifold that covers almost every point of the manifold?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

There is a standard definition of zero measure set on smooth manifold, which is used by Sard's theorem.

And my question is that, can we make a smooth manifold smoothly homeomorphic to an open set on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by removing a zero measure set?

Comment: This was asked and answered before. The key is that cut-locus has measure zero.